# asp.net Editable GridView - set Header text color

Tags: asp.net, css, gridview, header

In the asp.net editable gridview I have header text as 'FieldName *'.
As I am allowing user to enter the data and the data is mandatory.

Can I set FieldName with blue color and * with red color in header ??
If yes..how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert HTML code into the `HeaderText` for the `FieldName`.

Like this

`HeaderText="<font color="blue">FieldName </font><font color="red">*</font>"`

The page will interpret the HTML code and show it as you desire.
But you may have to set the `HtmlEncode` property for your `BoundField` in order to force the page to interpret the HTML code.

Comment: Are you sure you set the HtmlEncode to false? Like this `HtmlEncode="False"`? Otherwise it won't render. As a side note, mark as accepted answers that work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can make something out of this code.

```
     Protected Sub gvName_RowCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvIndexing.RowCreated
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header Then
        Dim oGridView As GridView = CType(sender, GridView)
        Dim oGridViewRow As GridViewRow = New GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Insert)
        Dim oTableCell As TableCell = New TableCell()

        oTableCell.Text = "Header Value"
        oTableCell.CssClass = "GridViewHeaderCSSClass"
        oTableCell.ColumnSpan = 2
        oGridViewRow.Cells.Add(oTableCell)
        oGridView.Controls(0).Controls.AddAt(0, oGridViewRow)
    Else
        Dim oGridView As GridView = CType(sender, GridView)
        oGridView.ShowHeader = False
    End If
End Sub
```